# Update Drawable in a layer-list dynamically for a widget

Tags: android, android-widget, drawable, layer-list

During the configuration phase of a widget, I would like to update a bitmap that is part of a layer-list. With all the restrictions of RemoteViews and Widgets, I see myself unable achieving this. Neither creating a new LayerDrawable manually nor retrieving and updating the drawable worked out. Do you have an idea?

Background: The Widget displays a Photo along with some other information. The photo should be framed and scale nicely, even if its sqare, landscape or portrait.

### Layer-List:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_01"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/photo_border"></item>
</layer-list>
```

The drawable @drawable/photo_border is a 9-patch bitmap.

### The corresponding part from the layout:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/framed_placeholder" />

</RelativeLayout>
<!-- ... -->
```

Thank You for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Instead of layer list how about just setting the imageview resource directly (and handle the layer list in code), i.e. remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.photo, yourBitmap); or remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.photo, yourResourceID); and update the widget using AppWidgetManager.

Comment: I found a solution, see answer below. Is that what You meant with "handling the layer list in code"? Or is there an alternative to rendering the Bitmap as I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While sleeping the problem over, I found, that I could probably just render the Bitmap manually and update the imageView. Here's the code. It's not nice, but get's the job done.

This probably can still be improved with better handling of density, etc.

```java
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + pathName);
Bitmap cBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(cBitmap);
c.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
NinePatchDrawable photo_border = (NinePatchDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo_border);
photo_border.setBounds(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
photo_border.draw(c);

views.setImageViewBitmap(id.photo, cBitmap);
```

One thing to be aware of: When the phone boots, the widgets may receive an Update event, when the sd card is not mounted. You should either wait until it is, or skip the configuration and add an intent-filter (that's what I did)

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
    <data android:scheme="file"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yes that's it, great work.  now just put some try { } catch { } in there when you decodeFile and createBitmap... and you have found yourself a solution (with the breadcrumb I provided in my previous comment).

Comment: True, the code is a snippet from a larger, unrefactored method that has a try and some catches :) One gotcha I just ran into: When the phone boots, the SD card may not be fully mounted. About to update my answer to include that.